# lagrange interpolation Python

Tags: python, scipy, interpolation, numerical-methods

I am trying to use `scipy.interpolate.lagrange` to interpolate the following data, which is of degree 8:

```
x_data = [1900., 1910., 1920., 1930., 1940., 1950., 1960., 1970., 1980.]

y_data = [76212168., 92228496., 106021537., 123202624., 132164569., 151325798., 179323175., 203302031., 226542199.]
```

with python code: `poly = scipy.interpolate.lagrange(x_data, y_data)`

But the output looks not correct because even none of the `(x_data[i], y_data[i])` pairs lies on the 'poly' I got from the `scipy.interpolate.lagrange` call.

Could anybody give any hints or suggestion?
Thanks so much.

Comment: Seems that you're looking for the function [*zip*](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip)

Answer (score 2):

Your values are poorly scaled, and, as the [`lagrange`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.lagrange.html) docstring says, "Warning: This implementation is numerically unstable."  Try applying `lagrange` to, say, the "whitened" data (i.e. shift and scale the data to have mean 0 and standard deviation 1).  For example,

```
xm = np.mean(x_data)
xscale = np.std(x_data)
ym = np.mean(y_data)
yscale = np.std(y_data)
x = (x_data - xm) / xscale
y = (y_data - ym) / yscale
poly = scipy.interpolate.lagrange(x, y)
```

(`np` comes from `import numpy as np`.)

Then to use `poly` on "raw" (i.e unscaled) data, use the same transform on the `x` input when you call `poly`, and undo the `y` transform on the values returned by `poly`.  E.g. if `xx` is an array with values in the interval [1900, 1980]:

```
yy = poly((xx - xm)/xscale)*yscale + ym
```

Before you spend too much time on this, though, I have to ask:
Why are you using Lagrange interpolation?  It is an important theoretical tool, but it is not so good for practical data analysis (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial#Notes; in particular, note the occurrence of Runge's phenomenon).  Why do you need to interpolate at all?  What are you going to do with the interpolator?  If you have answers to those questions, you should include them as part of the question.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4003794/lagrange-interpolation-in-python) create its own function a lagrange interpolation. Maybe you're using her